# How to disable MSI logging files presumably being generated by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, logging, windows-installer

I'm having this issue where I am getting a lot of MSI log files (the filename formats are MSIxxxx.LOG where xxxx corresponds to some random character sequence like "MSI974b5.LOG").
These log files are getting stored in the directory Windows/Temp. I should mention that I barely understand MSI log files or what they are used for (something about testing .msi installer files?).

I've tried the Microsoft support article for disabling MSI logging, but I'm still getting the MSI log files in my Windows/Temp directory. One thing I've noticed is that all of the MSI files mention "Visual Studio 12.0" somewhere in the log file, but beyond that I don't understand what is generating these log files or how to stop them from being generated.

I'm not sure if this is related but I recently installed Visual Studio 2013, but I don't remember enabling any MSI logging during the installation.

Comment: Are you referring to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 and the logging policy in the registry? Anyway, some more detail about what's in the log should help. There should be at least a product name somewhere. It's possible that there are repairs, which may mean there is an issue with your VS 2012 product install. Look for MsiInstaller log entries in the Application Event Log that may indicate what's being repaired. If they are all VS 2012 then it appears that the product is logging all install operations, but that's just the symptom - the issue could be repeated repair of a broken install.

Comment: I'm also referring to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545723 (includes a Fixit for disabling but doesn't work.) I tried looking through the logs and the only thing I can recognize is 'Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0'. I'm going to try repairing Visual Studio 2013 and see if the logs continue to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I'm answering my own situation, which may be too specific to be helpful to others

The MSI log files were being generated by a bad Visual Studio install. Ran the repair option provided with Visual Studio and the log files are no longer generated. Why the log files were being generated so frequently and without my knowledge I do not know but at least I think it stopped.

Answer (score 5):

See this bug on Microsoft Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/835600/visual-studio-2013-reconfiguration-via-windows-installer-fails-repeatedly-consumes-50gb-disk-space-in-msi-logs

Answer (score 4):

Check for a registry key named 'Logging' in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Installer. And just remove/rename this entry.

Comment: `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer /v Logging`  then  `reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer /v Logging`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by removing the key Vadim meant:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer\Logging
```

in my case it was set to `voicewarmupx`, which basically means "Log everything and a little more".
You can find more Information here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300/

Answer (score 1):

The solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/04/20/visual-studio-2013-continuously-repairs-producing-many-small-log-files.aspx) worked for me.

> 1. Open an elevated command prompt.
> 2. Type:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC
>    ```

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest .NET Framework version 4.6.2 solved the issue for me.